# howto examine c++ .o file under linux?

Tags: c++, linux, object

how can i examine a c++ .o file unter linux? is there any program with which i could easy examine it?

Comment: What do you need to find out about it?

Comment: need to find the name of functions which i overload, e.g. add(int a, int b) and add(float a, float b)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`objdump` is the command to analyze object files.

What do you want to check, exactly?

Answer (score 10):

A `.o` file is the translated output from compilation. It is *not* C++, even if the source code that generated it was written in C++. You could get an `.o` file from the compilation of source of any programming language.

Use `objdump` to look at `.o` files.

Answer (score 6):

You could also use the `nm` command.